# Creating an array of "users" inside another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am currently new to to vuejs and javascript. I want to create an array of "users" inside an entity called "service center". Here is my code.

```
data() {
    return {
      serviceCenters: [],
      users:[],
      currentServiceCenter: null,
      currentUser: null,
      currentIndex: -1,
      currentUserIndex: -1,
      id: "",
      searchValue: "",
    };
```

Here i have 2 arrays in the data object. serviceCenters which is the array that includes the list of all service centers and a users array which has the list of all users. However each service center has its own list of users in it where i can push or pop a user from. The list of service centers is returned using an api call in spring-boot. Here is the API call.

```
 retrieveServiceCenters() {
      ServiceCenterService.getAllServiceCenters()
        .then((response) => {
          this.serviceCenters = response.data;
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
      
    },
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: So, you want to get all users from `serviceCenters` and add to `users` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the `user` with the given `id` in the `users` list and do the same for `serviceCenter`, then check if `serviceCenter.users` already an array, then add the `user` to if not create new array and add the `user` to it too.

```
addUserToServiceCenters(userId, serviceCenterId) {
  const user = this.users.find(user => user.id === id);
  const serviceCenter = this.serviceCenters.find(s => s.id === serviceCenterId)
  serviceCenter.users = Array.isArray(serviceCenter.users) : [...serviceCenter.users, user] : [user]
}
```

Comment: Let me explain it a bit better. I have 2 separate arrays, a serviceCenters array and a users array. I already have 2 api getting all users and all serviceCenters arrays so both arrays in the data object contain the required information. 


What im trying to do now is adding a user from the users array to a separate users array within the serviceCenter array (maybe something like a multidimensional array).

Comment: Still not clear, please provide an example of data of  `serviceCenters` and `users` arrays and what is the expected output.

Comment: `serviceCenters [] array  contains
{
    name:
    usersForCurrentServiceCenter : [] 

}

users []{     (List of all users)    
  //user 1
 "name" :"x"
  "email":"x@gmail.com"

   //user 2
 "name" :"y"
  "email": "y@gmail.com"

}`
There is a button called **add this user to the chosen service center** . When clicked, The chosen user from the users list is added to the **users list inside the chosen  serviceCenter**

Comment: What is the unique value in the `user` does it has an `id`, if Yes, do when you click the button you have the `id` of the user You want to add?

Comment: Yes it does have an id and i also have the id of the user i want to add

Comment: Also, you have an id of the `serviceCenter` you want to add the user to, right?

Comment: Yes exactly. I choose both the serviceCenter and the user i want to add to that specific serviceCenter.

Comment: I updated the answer, please check again.

Comment: The answer is very close to the output i want. The only thing that i don't know how to do is how can i create a users list inside the serviceCenter array in the data object.

Comment: `serviceCenter.users = Array.isArray(serviceCenter.users) : [...serviceCenter.users, user] : [user]` already do that, you check if there are already a property inside `serviceCenter` called `users` and equal to `array` ( if not exist it will be equal `undefined` ), if it exist and equal to array ( We already add a user to it before ), then add the new user inside, if not ( we didn't add any user inside it before ), so create an empty array and add the user inside.